# MouseListener on a graphics object

Tags: java, swing, graphics, java-2d, mouselistener

I'm feeling quite stupid. But what is the reason why this simple piece of code doesn't change the ellipse's color?

Basically I want to add a mouse listener to the oval - a graphic object. when the mouse cursor is in oval, the oval changes its color. But this code doesn't change at all... This code is for testing only.

```
public class Help extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String [] agrs){
        Help h = new Help();
        h.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        h.add(new Help_Option());
        h.setSize(2000, 1000);
        h.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Help_Option extends JComponent implements MouseListener{
    Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 1000, 500);
    Color c = Color.BLACK;    

    public Help_Option(){
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.draw(ellipse);

        g2d.setColor(c);
        g2d.fill(ellipse);        
    }

    public void setColor(Color c){
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        if (ellipse.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()) ) {
            setColor(Color.GREEN);
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: no error! But it doesn't change the color ...

Comment: what dou you mean, "doesn't run at all"? does the compiler give an error (which?), the program give an exception (which?), or is it simply not doing anything?

Comment: oh i'm sorry! I'm gonna change my post!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are adding a `MouseListener` and waiting for `mouseEntered` events. These are fired when the mouse enters a *`Component`*, not a region of it. Try entering the component's boundary where the ellipse is shown and observe.

What you need is a `MouseMotionListener`, so that you can observe the mouse pixel by pixel; use the `mouseMoved` or `mouseDragged` events.

You might still need to listen for `mouseEntered` or `mouseExited` events, as `MouseMotionEvent`s are only fired while inside the component's boundary, so you might miss the mouse exiting the component while still inside the ellipse.

A good and simple way for debugging this is adding prints inside the event handler. You would then see that the handler was called, but only once or a few times, and not when you move the mouse within the component.

---

```
class Help_Option extends JComponent implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    Ellipse2D ellipse = ...;

    public Help_Option() {
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        if (ellipse.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()) ) {
            //mouse is inside the ellipse
        } else {
            //mouse is outside the ellipse
        }
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        //mouse is outside the ellipse
    }

    //more method stubs
}
```

Comment: but if i use the boundary of the ellipse, it would be a rectangle, so whenever my mouse enter the rectangle-but-not-in-ellipse, the color will change ... that's not what i really want...

Comment: Well, it works with mouse motion listener. but im quite curious, you can take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634107/is-there-any-way-to-add-a-mouselistener-to-a-graphic-object I did the same thing but ....

Comment: They are waiting for clicks, so it's not exactly the same thing. They don't have to detect the mouse entering or exiting the ellipse, but just know whether it's inside at a specific point. I have added some code clarifying how the detection would likely work

Answer (score 6):

> ..if i use the boundary of the ellipse, it would be a rectangle, so whenever my mouse enter the rectangle-but-not-in-ellipse, the color will change

See:

- [`Shape.contains(x,y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#contains-double-double-): Tests if the specified coordinates are inside the boundary of the `Shape`, as described by the definition of insideness.
- [`Shape.contains(Point2D)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#contains-java.awt.geom.Point2D-): Tests if a specified `Point2D` is inside the boundary of the `Shape`, as described by the definition of insideness.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556) for a demo showing collisions between 2 shapes.

[image]