# Mouse contain within object

Tags: java, mouselistener, jcomponent, contain

I'm new to learning Java and for a few days I have searched for a way to click drawn objects, to contain the mouse within a object such as g.drawRect(x, x, x, x)...

I came across the code below, I'm trying to make it work so I can learn what is needed to contain the mouse within a object but I cant seem to make it work.

Got code from " [Is there any way to add a MouseListener to a Graphic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634107/is-there-any-way-to-add-a-mouselistener-to-a-graphic-object) "

I've tried to make it work according to the tips they gave but no hope :(.

Any help is appreciated.

```js
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui3 extends JFrame {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  MyDrawPanel drawpanel = new MyDrawPanel();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gui3 gui = new Gui3();
    gui.go();
  }

  public void go() {

    frame.getContentPane().add(drawpanel);
    // frame.addMouseListener(this);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }

}

class MyDrawPanel extends JComponent implements MouseListener {

  Ellipse2D oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(70, 70, 100, 100);

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.fillOval(70, 70, 100, 100);

  }

  @
  Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if ((e.getButton() == 1) && oval.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
      repaint();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getX() + "\n" + e.getY());
    }
  }

  @
  Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @
  Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @
  Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

  }

  @
  Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    return oval.contains(x, y);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your commented line hints at your issue - you never actually add a MouseListener to the GUI, so no one is being notified of mouse events. It appears you've made your panel the mouse listener (which is fine), so register it in a constructor for the `MyDrawPanel` class. Add this constructor to your MyDrawPanel, and  you should be good to go.

```
public MyDrawPanel(){
    addMouseListener(this);
}
```

Also, it would probably be a good idea to draw your actual `oval` variable instead of using the `drawOval(..)` method of Graphics, because you are creating a shape in memory and an image that are disjoint from one another. Try this instead for your `paintComponent(Graphics g)`:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.fill(oval);
}
```

Comment: This is going to screw with the `MouseEvent` context as the event context will be the frame and not the `drawPanel`...

Comment: It was actually working fine for me when I tried it, but I'll move it to the drawpanel constructor.

Comment: The frame has borders, which will  put the mouse out by the width of the border (2~4 pixels on Windows) and by the frames title bar (~25 pixels on Windows), so if you try and click in the bottom/right corner of the ellipse, you will miss it.  You can test this by painting the mouse click points on the `MyDrawPanel`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to register the `MouseListener` with the `DrawPanel`, you want to do this, because you want the mouse events to be within the context of the `DrawPanel` otherwise the `MouseEvent` location information won't be correct.

```
class MyDrawPanel extends JComponent implements MouseListener {

    Ellipse2D oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(70, 70, 100, 100);

    public MyDrawPanel() {
        addMouseListener(this);
    }
```

You will also want to call `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.fillOval(70, 70, 100, 100);

}
```

You should also ensure that you are creating/modifying your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            Gui3 gui = new Gui3();
            gui.go();
        }
    });
}
```