# Add MouseListener to java.awt.Image

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way I can add a MouseListener to an Image?
I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634107/is-there-any-way-to-add-a-mouselistener-to-a-graphic-object) StackOverflow question, but it didn't really answer how to do this for a `java.awt.Image`, as there is no Graphics2D Image class. Or at least one I've found.

---

**EDIT:**

To clarify, let me try to explain:

With a `Ellipse2D`, I can say:

```
if(ellipse2D.contains(mouseX, mouseY) {
    ...do something
}
```

Is this possible with a `java.awt.Image` (i.e. `image.contains()`)

Also, this is how the Image gets added to the JPanel:

```
Image image = item.getIcon().getImage(); //item.getIcon() returns a javax.swing.ImageIcon
g.drawImage(image, imageX, imageY, null);
```

Comment: You should have some container the image is displayed in, then add the listener there.

Comment: It's actually quite a bit more complicated that that. The program uses a for loop and adds several images, and I need an easy way to programmatically find if you clicked on an image. I don't exactly know where the image is going to be placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put the image in a JLabel and add the listener to the JLabel

```
ImageIcon image = item.getIcon();
JLabel labelWithImage = new JLabel(image);
labelWithImage.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Entered Over Image");
    }
});
panel.add(labelWithImage);
```

Comment: But why? He could just do this and everything will work. I understand that that is what he is doing right now, but this is a solution to his problem.